# Second bufio.Scanner for stdin does not read anything

Tags: go

I'm having some trouble with reading from stdin using Go with `bufio.Scanner`.

Let's say I have input like this

```
1 5
2 3
4 5
```

I'm trying to read each line with a call to this function:

```golang
    func get_arg_multi_int(params *[]int) {
        var line string
        var scanner *bufio.Scanner = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

        if scanner.Scan() {

            line = scanner.Text()
            for _, x := range strings.Fields(line) {
                i, _ := strconv.Atoi(x)
                *params = append(*params, i)
            }

        }

        if err:= scanner.Err(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
```

After three calls to `get_arg_multi_int` I would expect `params` to be populated (each time) as:

```
[1, 5]
[2, 3]
[4, 5]
```

Instead I get the following:

```
[1, 5]
[]
[]
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I suspect it has something to do with opening stdin multiple times, but I can't seem to find any (easily accessible) documentation that tells me what exactly happens when scanner goes out of scope.

I wouldn't be surprised to learn there is some more idiomatic way to achieve what the above code is trying to do, but I am very curious as to *why* this code doesn't work.

Could someone comment on why I am not seeing the expected behavior?

Thanks,

Comment: Does it not just read up to the next token token like a new line? For example, if I changed the if statement to a for loop, each iteration would corresponding to adding the contents of a line to `params`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that. The point of `bufio` is that it's *buffered* I/O. Your `Scanner` might have consumed any amount of data from stdin, beyond the single line that you asked for, and held it in its own buffer. That data doesn't get "put back" into stdin. If you make a new `Scanner` without reading the first one to EOF, you will get unpredictable and un-useful results. You need to use a single `Scanner`, not keep making new ones. Or, if reading linewise isn't the only thing you will ever want to do, you may be better off with a `bufio.Reader` instead of a `Scanner`.

Comment: This makes complete sense to me. Thanks!

Comment: As a small follow up, how does one then just read a single line from stdin, move on (as in return from some sort of read function and then do other things), and then possible continue to read from stdin later? Wouldn't this buffer mechanism make that a bit difficult?

Comment: @tnibbles that's where the `bufio.Reader` comes in handy. It's buffered, and its `ReadLine`, `ReadSlice` and `ReadString` methods support the same uses as a Scanner does, but it also has all of the regular `io.Reader` methods — except they're aware of the buffer.

Comment: @tnibbles and yes, it's kind of an inconvenience, but since I/O streams can't be counted on to go backwards, the only way to read a line without something like bufio is to read one byte at a time, so that you never read beyond the newline. That's inefficient.